# Pytest - How to test all files in certain path ignoring errors?

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

My question should be simple:
Is there any way of running all tests in a certain path using the `pytest -v` command?

Run should behave in a way that if there are assertion errors in one of the files, the check will continue with other files as well, and not stop the whole testing procedure upon first assert error.

Comment: This is exactly how pytest works by default — after an AssertionError it skips the test but continue with other tests in the file and continue other files. To make pytest stop at the first error there is a command line parameter (`-x`). So what is you problem exactly?

Comment: pytest skip other files upon error on one of the tests files

Comment: It does not, unless there was an error while collecting the tests. Can you show the output you get?

Comment: @JavaSa can I ask you to do an experiment — comment out the test that produces the error and verify all other tests work. Please report. I suspect the problem is not with the failing test.